# What is the principle of scanner

Tags: nrf24l01+, wireless, rf

I find a 2.4GHz scanner in this [web](https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/Nrf24L01-Poor+Man%27s+2.4+GHz+Scanner) . I want to do same thing in 433 Mhz with SI4463. But I fail to understand it's principle. Who can explain it ? Thanks.

> [image]

Comment: This might help; http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/AN633.pdf

Comment: `But I fail to understand it's principle.` - what principle do you want explained exactly? I don't see what this is to do with Arduinos.

Comment: @NickGammon  I don't know the algorithm i.e how does it work.

Comment: @MikaelPatel  It's too hard for me ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I find a 2.4GHz scanner in this web . I want to do same thing in 433
>   Mhz with SI4463. But I fail to understand it's principle. Who can
>   explain it ?

The scanner you found loops through the channels looking for activity. The channels are defined by the NRF24L01. And activity is received signal within the channel above threshold (RSSI). For this device this is a single bit.

Other devices define RSSI as the signal quality/level for the latest received package. This is the case for the SI4463.

Cheers!

Comment: I use http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/classRH__RF24.html   to control SI4463, but the RSSI is zero although there is a interference at same frequency . Do you know how to do it ?

Comment: Please post your test program/code.

Comment: BW: The RSSI value from SI4463 is for the latest received package. Interference is not detected by the RSSI in this case.

Comment: Yes, so ,I don't know how to do the same thing. And I have add my code in my question. Thanks very much.

Comment: @MikaelPatel - What the 446x RSSI means depends on what mode it is operating in.  If the poster wants to measure things that are not compatible signals, they probably do not want to be operating in packet mode.

Comment: @MikaelPatel  I think you are right. But I can't find a suitable mode in RH_RF24.